# using different code for different stages and deploying it on AWS ECS

Tags: python, docker, deployment, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to push 2 dockers for ECS: 1 for dev, where I test my code, and one for production.
The dockers use a third-party API, where the dev API is different from the prod API.
I'm trying to build it locally in a way that I can merge and moved smoothly between stages, and then deploy easily to the right docker.

I've tried that:

```
  from pygit2 import Repository

repo = Repository('.')
print(f"repo.head:{repo.head}")
if 'main' or 'demo' in repo.head:
    api_var= API_ADDRESS_FOR_PROD
else:
    api_var = API_ADDRESS_FOR_DEV
```

but the ECS is sending this error:

```
_pygit2.GitError: Repository not found at .
```

How can I assign different values to different branches locally, while the ECS accepts them with no error?

Comment: Why do you need pygit2? Why do you need to interreact with a Git repository here? Is the API so different that you have two completely different Git repositories for your dev and production code? Also, does this docker container run locally without errors?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm using pygit2 to get the current branch that I'm working on (i.e., STAGE, dev/prod). The API key must be different between those stages. And yes, the docker runs locally without errors.

Comment: It's really strange to be performing Git actions on the code that is running inside the Docker container. If the only difference in the dev/prod environments is an API key, then you should be setting those keys as environment variables. If there are more differences, then you could also set an environment name (dev or prod) as another environment variable, and have the conditional checks in your code that check that value.